# how do i remove the slash in url ,using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

this my website mapping

```
--domain.com

------mainpage

---------index.php
```

my domain.com inside have a mainpage folder and inside the the folder have a index.php.

the url now

```
http://domain.com/mainpage/
```

the url i wanted(removing the slash)

```
http://domain.com/mainpage
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !directory/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/mainpage/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mainpage$ /mainpage/index.php [L]
```